# Normal vectors of planes intersecting a tetahedron: is my calculation correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need some help with basic linear algebra. The setting is this:

Imagine a cube with endpoints $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$ sitting in $\mathbb R^3$. Color all vertices with even sign. This gives a tetrahedron inside the cube.  Let's label the colored vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$.

I am trying to determine normal vectors of planes of reflection of this tetrahedron and the reflection matrices.

> Could someone please tell me if what I did is right?

Part of my work (all the calculations are the same so I'm only posting one):

We have the following vertices: $v_1 = (1,1,1), v_2 = (-1,-1,1), v_3 = (-1,1,-1), v_4 = (1,-1,-1)$.

The normal for $v_2,v_4$ is:

$$ v_2 - v_4 = (-2,0,2), \|v_2-v_4\| = \sqrt{8}, n = {1\over \sqrt{8}} (-2,0,2)$$

and the rotation matrix is:

$$ I - nn^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} -{1\over 8} \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -4 & 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix} =  {1\over 2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0&  2 & 0  \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The reflection is $I - 2 n n^{T}$ (you are off by a factor of $2$).  Get 
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

It's better to look at the reflection of the tetrahedron as some reflections of the cube, the ones wr to diagonal planes.  The formulae should follow right away.